# Fetch using cached data when no internet connection - Javascript - React

Tags: javascript, caching, fetch

I have a webapp that needs to use cached data when there's no internet connection. I have it working well now using a second fetch call inside the catch block but I feel this isn't the right approach.

```
    fetch(api)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(json => {
        this.setState({ 
            result: json.Results,
        })
    })
    .catch(e => {
        const options = {
            cache: "force-cache"
        }
        fetch(api, options)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(`failed to fetch --- using cached data`)
            this.setState({ 
                result: json.Results,
            })
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error("Insufficient data")
        })
    })
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Not long ago, this began to stop working. I think its due to the the bad response screwing with the cache. Not sure if the browser compatibility (Chrome and Chromium) changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking for navigator.onLine was an easy conditional to avoid any issues.

https://davidwalsh.name/detecting-online

Comment: While the link may help finding answer to the question, add the relevant details in the answer itself. In case the external link is modified, the answer will not be helpful anymore

Comment: I think the question was sufficiently answered in the text above the link.

Comment: navigator.online returns true even when you are connected to a network without internet. I don't think it should be a definitive test for 'Internet connection'

Comment: What would be a for sure way to do so?